# Quartz scheduling queues up missed scheduled jobs

Tags: quartz.net

I have a quartz job schedule like so:

```
_scheduler.ScheduleJob(job,
    TriggerBuilder.Create().ForJob(job)
        .WithSimpleSchedule(x =>                                             
        x.WithIntervalInSeconds(requeryTime.ToInt32())
        .RepeatForever()
        .WithMisfireHandlingInstructionNowWithRemainingCount()                                             
    )                                        
    .StartNow()
    .Build())
```

To test I have the schedule run every 10 seconds. If I pause the service and then resume, I can still see all the jobs being called one after another. I want Quartz to ignore (do not queue) the jobs and just resume the schedule.
e.g. If the job runs every 10 secs and I pause the service for 1 minute, I get 6 jobs run in quick succession.

How do I go about ensuring Quartz ignores those jobs?

Comment: Any feedback on this?

Comment: I need to re-assess the conditions which cause this. I was pausing my app in a console window and I'm not sure this is a good test. Pausing the app effectively pauses the quartz scheduler and so schedules jobs all at once (queues them up). I'm not sure if this is the same as jobs being scheduled whilst it is already busy.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is to change the `misfireThreshold` in the configuration:

```
<add key="quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold" value="60000" />
```

The default is 60000 milliseconds (60 seconds).

[org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/configuration/ConfigRAMJobStore)

> The the number of milliseconds the scheduler will 'tolerate' a trigger
>   to pass its next-fire-time by, before being considered "misfired". The
>   default value (if you don't make an entry of this property in your
>   configuration) is 60000 (60 seconds).

Since your trigger runs every 10 seconds you can reduce the threshold to 9 seconds and it should work as you expect.

If you want to learn more about the strategies involved you can read this [article](http://royontechnology.blogspot.co.uk/2009/03/so-you-think-you-understand.html) and [this](http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2012/04/quartz-scheduler-misfire-instructions.html) one as well.

A similar question has been asked recenlty and [Circular Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2013954/circular-reference) gave a really good [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30400396/219406).